# One TD disappearing on mobile?

Tags: html, css, email, mobile, responsive

I've got an email layout that functions as one wide column with two smaller columns at the bottom to keep a pair of linked images horizontal. Currently I'm struggling to get the layout to play nicely on mobile—if I can get the table to fill the screen, the leftmost image vanishes entirely, and if I can get both buttons to appear horizontally on mobile, the container breaks. My understanding of responsive layouts is spotty but I'm trying to figure out how to make this work nicely—complicated not least of all because my customer base tilts heavily Outlook.

CSS and HTML below. Appreciate any help!

```css
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"><head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"></head><body class="em_body" style="margin:0px auto; padding:0px;" bgcolor="#f7f6f2">   <u></u>
    <!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
    <o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
    <o:AllowPNG/>
    <o:PixelsPerInch>96</o:PixelsPerInch>
    </o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
    </xml><![endif]-->
    <title>Lorem </title>
    
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0 ">
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
    
    <!--[if !mso]><!-->
    <style>
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato:wght@300;400;700;900&display=swap');
    </style> 
    <!--<![endif]-->
    <!--[if mso]>
    <style type="text/css">
    body, table, td {font-family: Trebuchet MS, sans-serif !important;}
    </style>
    <![endif]-->
    <style type="text/css">
    body { margin: 0 auto; padding: 0; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100% !important; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100% !important; -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased !important; }
    img { border: 0 !important; outline: none !important; }
    p { Margin: 0px auto !important; Padding: 0px !important; }
    table { border-collapse: collapse; mso-table-lspace: 0px; mso-table-rspace: 0px; }
    td, a, span { border-collapse: collapse; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; }
    .ExternalClass * { line-height: 100%; }
    .em_defaultlink a { color: inherit !important; text-decoration: none !important; }
    .em_defaultlinku a { color: inherit !important; text-decoration: underline !important; }
    .em_g_img + div { display: none; }
    a[x-apple-data-detectors], u + .em_body a, #MessageViewBody a { color: inherit !important; text-decoration: none !important; font-size: inherit !important; font-family: inherit !important; font-weight: inherit !important; line-height: inherit !important; }
    .em_white a { color: #ffffff; text-decoration: none; }
    .em_black a { color: #000000; text-decoration: none; }
    .em_grey a{text-decoration:underline; color: #5e687b;}
    .cta_insta a:hover{opacity:0.8 !important;}
     @media only screen and (max-width:599px) {
    .em_main_table { width: 100% !important; }
    .em_wrapper { width: 100% !important; }
    .em_hide { display: none !important; }
    .em_full_img img { width: 100% !important; height: auto !important; }
    .em_center { text-align: center !important; }
    .em_side10 { width: 10px !important; }
    .em_aside10 { padding: 0px 10px !important; }
    .em_side15 { width: 15px !important; }
    .em_aside15 { padding: 0px 15px !important; }
    .em_ptop { padding-top: 20px !important; }
    .em_pbottom { padding-bottom: 20px !important; }
    .em_h20 { height: 20px !important; font-size: 1px!important; line-height: 1px!important; }
    .em_h30 { height: 30px !important; }
    .em_mob_block { display: block !important; }
    .em_hauto { height: auto !important; }
    .em_clear { clear: both !important; width: 100% !important; display: block !important; }
    .em_pad { padding: 15px 0px!important; }
    .em_p0 { padding: 0px !important; }
    u + .em_body .em_full_wrap { width: 100% !important; width: 100vw !important; }
    }
     @media screen and (max-width: 479px) {
    .em_w250 img{width: 250px !important; height: auto !important;}
    }
    </style>
```

```html
    
    
    <!-- == Header Section == -->
    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="em_full_wrap" bgcolor="#f7f6f2" style="table-layout:fixed;">
      <tbody><tr>
        <td align="center" valign="top"><table align="center" width="600" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="em_main_table" style="width:600px; table-layout:fixed;">
            <tbody><tr>
              <td width="20" style="width: 20px;" class="em_side15"> </td>
                <td align="center" valign="top" style="padding: 10px 0px;">
                    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
                      <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="em_defaultlinku" align="left" valign="top" style="font-size: 11px;line-height: 19px; font-family: 'Segoe', 'Lato', Trebuchet MS, sans-serif; color: #5e687b;">
                    A project of the <a style="text-decoration: underline; color: #5e687b;" target="_blank" href="" sib_link_id="-2"><span style="text-decoration: underline; color: #5e687b;">me</span></a>
                            </td>
                            <td class="em_defaultlinku" align="right" valign="top" style="font-size: 11px;line-height: 19px; font-family: 'Segoe', 'Lato', Trebuchet MS, sans-serif; color: #5e687b;"><a style="text-decoration: underline; color: #5e687b;" target="_blank" href="https://4gyqr.r.bh.d.sendibt3.com/mk/cl/f/XUnKP49MNRJGqrTlNljomt86K0iNsgdAd6geoccV9wjEoMk4WDUFVtfu35Pch2qMizkrVxMHdgNeKkma-D8pvKI4brXSZeUJcwGASatkf8QC7fvoy2lzRiF_nJ3iplyaHM_VMwh7WfRCLNOA_b_UZgVhaDjK93nLSRu-xdfS9NFxUKEeDSfMmwENzXkMGHNu_L__CmSYdD3h4oaUPw_Ec4Bqf9Oe07sJYlx-plI36Pr30fP3MilbymBwzRvgWQ" sib_link_id="-2"><span style="text-decoration: underline; color: #5e687b;">View in browser</span></a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                </td>
                <td width="20" style="width: 20px;" class="em_side15"> </td>
                
    
            </tr>
          </tbody></table></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody></table>
    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="em_full_wrap" bgcolor="#3c81b7" style="table-layout:fixed;">
      <tbody><tr>
        <td align="center" valign="top" class="em_aside10"><table align="center" width="600" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="em_main_table" style="width:600px; table-layout:fixed;">
            
            <tbody><tr>
                <td align="center" valign="top">
                    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
                      <tbody>
                        <tr>
              <td width="15" style="width: 15px;"> </td>
                <td align="center" valign="top" style="padding: 33px 0px 34px;" class="em_pad">
                    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
                      <tbody>
                        <tr>
                          <td align="center" valign="top" class="em_w250">
                            <a href="" target="_blank" style="text-decoration: none;" sib_link_id="-2">
                              <img src="" width="600px" alt="" border="0" style="display: block; max-width: 600px; font-size: 14px; font-family: Trebuchet MS, sans-sarif;  line-height: 16px; color: #ffffff; font-weight: bold;" sib_img_id="0" sib_img_id="6"> </a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                </td>
                <td width="15" style="width: 15px;"> </td>
            </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
    
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center" valign="top" class="em_full_img">
                     <img style="display: block; max-height: 600px;" border="0" alt="" width="600" src="https://img.mailinblue.com/2622083/images/rnb/original/5e5ea936a209c5f1bb63e3a4.png?t=1603303476946" sib_img_id="1" sib_img_id="7">
                </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody></table></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
    <!-- == //Header Section == --> 
    <!-- == Body Section == -->
    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="em_full_wrap" bgcolor="#f7f6f2" style="table-layout:fixed;">
      <tbody>
          <tr>
        <td align="center" valign="top" class="em_aside10">
            <table align="center" width="600" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="em_main_table" style="width:600px; table-layout:fixed;">
            <!-- Banner section -->
            <tbody>
                <tr>
              <td align="center" valign="top">
                    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" bgcolor="#ffffff">
                      <tbody>
                        <tr>
                          <td width="20" style="width: 20px;" class="em_side15"> </td>
                            <td align="center" valign="top" style="padding: 10px 0px 10px;" class="em_pad">
                                <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
                                      <tbody>
                                                              <tr>
                                          <td class="em_defaultlink" align="left" valign="top" style="font-size: 18px; font-family: 'Segoe', 'Lato', Trebuchet MS, sans-serif;  line-height: 26px; color: #5e687b;">
                                        <br>
                                        <p><span style="font-size:22px; color:#ed7d31;"><strong>Title</strong></span></p>
                                    <br>
        <p><span style="font-size:18px; color:#ed7d31;">Subtitle</span></p>
        <br>
        <p><span style="font-size:18px;">"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</span></p><br>
    
                                              <p>Download the app today at: </p>
                            </td>
                </tr>
                        </tbody>
                 
                 
                        <table dir="ltr" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10" align="center" class="tablescale">
                            <tbody>
                            <tr>
                           <td>
                            <a href="" sib_link_id="-2"><img src="https://img.mailinblue.com/2622083/images/rnb/original/5f8f1501bf3088251f084b30.png?t=1603303691818" width="230" style="margin:6%;width:88%"></a>
                        </td>
            <td>
                <a href="" sib_link_id="-2"><img src="https://img.mailinblue.com/2622083/images/rnb/original/5f8f1535c87258058403a4b3.png?t=1603303702894" width="280"></a>
            </td> 
        </table>
                 
                            </td>
                           <td width="20" style="width: 20px;" class="em_side15"> </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                          </table>
                                
                            </td>    
                        </tr>
                        
                                
                
                                      </tbody>
              
                
                    </table>
    
            
            <tr>
                <td align="center" valign="top" class="em_full_img">
                     <img style="display: block; max-height: 600px;" border="0" alt="" width="600" src="https://img.mailinblue.com/2622083/images/rnb/original/5e5ea90ba8a748ea77252c11.png?t=1603303468240" sib_img_id="4" sib_img_id="10">
                </td>
            </tr>
        
            </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody></table>
    <!-- == //Body Section == --> 
    <!-- == Footer Section == -->
    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="em_full_wrap" bgcolor="#f7f6f2" style="table-layout:fixed;">
      <tbody><tr>
        <td align="center" valign="top"><table align="center" width="500" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="em_main_table" style="width:500px; table-layout:fixed;" bgcolor="#f7f6f2">
            <tbody><tr>
              <td align="center" valign="top">
                    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
                          <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                          <td class="em_grey em_ptop" align="left" valign="top" style="font-size: 12px; font-family: 'Segoe', 'Lato', Trebuchet MS, sans-serif;  line-height: 19px; color: #9a9ca0; padding-top: 30px;">
                                            We sent this email to <a style="text-decoration:underline;color: #5e687b;" href="mailto:{{contact_email}}">{{contact_email}}</a> because you signed up.
    <br><br>
```

Answer (score 0):

i make this solution that solve your problem but i think the main problem is the picture frame of g play it has more "white space". i hope i was helpful, have a good day.

```html
<tbody>
  <tr>
     <td>
        <a href="" sib_link_id="-2">
          <img src="https://img.mailinblue.com/2622083/images/rnb/original/5f8f1501bf3088251f084b30.png?t=1603303691818" style="max-width:200px;width:100%">
        </a>
     </td>
     <td>
        <a href="" sib_link_id="-2">
          <img src="https://img.mailinblue.com/2622083/images/rnb/original/5f8f1535c87258058403a4b3.png?t=1603303702894" style="max-width:255px;width:100%">
        </a>
      </td> 
    </tr>
</tbody>
```